# importacao e exportacao arquivo .txt FILE em C

Tags: c

O algoritmo deve ler de 1000 a 15000 ( 1 mil a 15 mil) numeros reais, somar todos e realizar uma media, eu fiz varios processos de importacao, e exportacao de resultado final, mas nenhum copilou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int count,count_auxiliar;
float media;
float entrada[10]; 

/*
    FAZER IMPORTACAO NESTE MOMENTO
*/
//para coontador de 0 ate nenhuma entrada, contador recebe +1
for(count=0; count!=EOF; count++)
{
    // le entrada de arquivo
    scanf("%f",&entrada[count]);
    //contador auxiliar tem como funcao usar mesmo valor de contador mas sem alterar nada apenas para auxiliar no calculo da media
    count_auxiliar=count;

    // realiza media de arquivo de entrada
    media=entrada[count]+media;
    count_auxiliar--;
    media=media / count_auxiliar;
}

/*
    FAZER EXPORTACAO DE RESULTADO FINAL "MEDIA"
*/

return 0;
}
```

Vou deixar o codigo e comentar onde preciso de auxilio, no caso importar um arquivo TXT, com N valores ler todos e calcular uma media, e dar resultado final em outro arquivo TXT.

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, você está lendo os números da entrada padrão (`stdin`), não de um arquivo .txt. É isso mesmo que você quer fazer?

Em segundo lugar, o que você está fazendo com `count` é muito esquisito. Por quê você começa no zero, incrementa a cada número, e fica esperando o número ser `EOF`(= -1)?  Para testar se um *stream* acabou, você usa `feof(FILE *)`, neste caso `feof(stdin)`.

Também passar `&entrada[count]` para o `scanf()` faz com que ele vá escrevendo em partes no *array* até ele ler o 11º número, quando ele escreve fora do *array* e sacaneia a sua pilha.

O melhor é refazer o programa todo, com uma função que recebe o arquivo aberto, lê todos os números, e retorna a média deles. Pra isto, basta um `double` para servir de acumulador e um `int` para contar a quantidade de números lidos.

Então:

```
double
calcular_media(FILE * input) {
    double accum = 0.0, tmp = 0.0;
    int count = 0;

    while (!feof(input)) {
        if (fscanf(input, "%lf ", &tmp) < 1)
            exit(-1); // Se houve erro de leitura, quebre
        accum += tmp;
        count ++;
    }

    return accum / count;
}
```

A parte de abrir o arquivo de entrada, chamar `calcular_media()` e escrever o arquivo de saída você consegue fazer, certo?

Comment: na real nao manjo muito de programação, entao o que puder me ajudar eu agradeço, se possivel manda teu whatsapp ai que fica mais facil! ai eu te explico tudo bem detalhado!

Comment: @AGenaro: Eu não ligo de mandar o meu Whatsapp, mas o ideal era que nós pudéssemos dirimir o máximo das suas dúvidas aqui no _site_ para que isto possa ajudar outros que depois encontrem esta pergunta e que tenham as mesmas dúvidas que você...